How to Generate Swagger Specification for Versioned APIs in a Single Route File Using Go-Swagger?
I'm working on a Golang project where I have a backend server with multiple API versions defined in a single route file. I'm using the go-swagger package to generate Swagger documentation.
I have the following setup for my routes:
r := chi.NewRouter()

// swagger:operation POST /v1/resource AddResourceDetails
r.Post("/v1/resource", resourceHandler.AddResourceDetails)

// swagger:operation POST /v2/resource AddResourceDetails
r.Post("/v2/resource", resourceHandler.AddResourceDetails)

I want to know how to properly annotate my handler functions for Swagger to generate different spec files for each API version.

Add v1, v2 tags to the relevent routes using the following pattern:
swagger:route [method] [path pattern] [?tag1 tag2 tag3] [operation id]

And add an --include-tag= option in the generation command, this will generate a spec file only for the given tag. Note that it can be specified many times.

Thanks! I have one more question: Like include-tag includes operations in spec file having a specified tag, is there an option that includes operations matching a specified route pattern?

All available options are described in the documentation. It doesn't seem to contains what you're asking for.
